# Firebase Functions: update all documents inside a collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a function for Firebase that update all the documents inside a specific collection when another type of document is updated.

```
functions.firestore.document('/accounts/{accountId}/resources/{resourceId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const resource = context.params.resourceId;
    admin.firestore().collection('/accounts/'+account+'/tasks')
      .where('resourceId', '=', resource).get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          doc.update({
            fieldA: 'valueA',
            fieldB: 'valueB'
          });
        });
        return true;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

This is not working, but i don't know how to do it, it's the first time i make a function for Firebase.

Comment: You say it's not working, what's happening? Is anything getting updated? Is nothing getting updated? Is your computer connected to the internet? We need more details

Comment: It doesn'd update the document, i deploy the function and i get no error so the syntax is correct. When i update a document inside resources it doesn't update the other documents of the other collection. I also tried this inside the forEach instead of using doc: admin.firestore.collection('/accounts/'+account+'/tasks').doc(doc.id).update({})

Comment: can you return the promise of operation, like "return admin.firestore()....."

Comment: i tried but nothing changed

Comment: pretty sure single = is not a where operator, if you change it to this the query should work `.where('resourceId', '==', resource)` if that works let me know

Comment: You're ignoring all the promises generated by calls to the Admin SDK.  You need to handle them all correctly and return a single promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.  It might be helpful for you to watch this video series.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
functions.firestore.document('/accounts/{accountId}/resources/{resourceId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const resource = context.params.resourceId;

    return admin.firestore().collection('/accounts/'+account+'/tasks')
      .where('resourceId', '=', resource).get().then(snapshot => {
        const promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          promises.push(doc.ref.update({
            fieldA: 'valueA',
            fieldB: 'valueB'
          }));
        });
        return Promise.all(promises)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return null;
    });
});
```

Note:

1. The `return` in `return admin.firestore()....`
2. That in `forEach()` you get
   [`QueryDocumentSnapshots`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) so you have to do `doc.ref.update()`
3. The use of `Promise.all()` since you execute several asynchronous methods in parallel.

As Doug advised in his comment, you should watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: congratulations on 10k reputation!

Comment: @PeterHaddad Thanks! :-) It's kind of you! And congrats for the 20k!

Comment: In this answer, the whole documents are retrieved although only their references are required for the update operation. Is there a way to get only the references of the documents inside a collection?

Comment: @Montaner No, with the JS SDK, for a CollectionReference the only way is to use the get() method, which returns the results as a QuerySnapshot.

Comment: @PeterHaddad , RenaudTarnec, well ain't love grand.. Ya'll gon lay down in the snow and make snow angels together?